# Accessing tableau server from cloud machine

Tags: tableau-api

I wanted to embedded tableau dashboard into webapp which is hosted on Azure VM.
But i am unable to access tableau server from VM machine.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Is your Tableau Server inside of your intranet? Is your firewall allowing connections from outside?

Comment: No.I wanted to access tableau server out of intranet.

Comment: That isn't really answering Sam M's question. Where is the Tableau Server machine located right now? Can it be accessed from any other machine that is outside of its current network?

Comment: With the little info provided in the question, I'm guessing here. My first suspicion is that your firewall is preventing the Azure VM from accessing Tableau Server. Firewall settings would be outside the scope of stackoverflow but talk with whomever administers your firewall. They will know how to check if it's the firewall and how to allow the connection through (if they'll allow it).

Answer (score 0):

You will need an account on the Tableau Server. Everybody who needs access to view an embedded dashboard will need an account on the Tableau Server.  I assume you'll use SAML or Trusted Auth?

Comment: Yes,i do have account on tableau server.Problem is i am not able to access tableau sever from azure vm. Is there any setting or configuration i need to do to access it?

Comment: Yes, i believe Sam M has your answer.  You'll need to speak with whomever setup your Azure instance.  They can potentially grant you access by configuring firewall/security rules.